# Letters are missing with calligra

Tags: fonts, characters

Whith `\calligra`, letters like `\` and `\u{g}` disappear. How can I fix this?

See the demo below. Without calligra, it works. With, it doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
 \usepackage[cam,width=4truein,height=6truein,letter,center] {crop}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{calligra}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{anysize}
 \usepackage{background}
 \usepackage{graphics}
 \marginsize{2cm}{2cm}{6.6cm}{1cm}


 \thispagestyle{empty}

  \backgroundsetup{scale=0.5,angle=0,opacity=0.6,position={16.5cm,-15.0cm},contents={\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{wedding-rings-2400px}}}

\begin{document}


  \crop
  \begin{center}

  {\calligra \small K{\i}z \u{g}ını} \\
  {\small K{\i}z \u{g}ını}\\

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you do not need `wedding-rings-2400px` to show the issue please edit the example not to use files and packages that are not needed

Comment: The glyph inventory of `calligra` is not the whole of T1; it indeed lacks `ı` (dotless i) and `ḡ` (g with breve). The latter can be perhaps remedied to, the former can't.

Comment: @egreg can't ... unless you hit it with a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font doesn't have the dotless i or g-breve  but you can take the accent from another font and use a dotted i but hide the dot, or as Ulrike points out the font does have a (very stylized) breve accent so you can add `\relax` to stop LaTeX trying to use the composite letter :

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{color}
\def\ci{i\rlap{\textcolor{white}{\kern2pt\rule{2pt}{7pt}}}}

\begin{document}


  {\calligra  K\ci z \raisebox{-2pt}{\rmfamily\u{}}\kern-6pt g\ci n\ci}

  {\calligra  K\ci z \u{\relax g}\ci n\ci}

  { K{\i}z \u{g}ını}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't dare to test this at other fontsizes ... ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if you do, I'll [build you a bigger sledgehammer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530496/letters-are-missing-with-calligra/530504?noredirect=1#comment1341494_530496)

Comment: I would also need a tiny one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer troublemakers are not invited to the wedding

Comment: There is a breve accent in the font, you could use it with `\DeclareTextAccent{\mybreve}{T1}{8}`. Do I get an invitation now???

Comment: @UlrikeFischer answer updated thanks (but no:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and David Carlisle. Thank you for having this funny conversation. I send my congratulations (or condolences) to the wedding.